# regex \X is not reggniced by .Net 6.0 regex.replace is there an alternative?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to use the follwing regex https://regex101.com/library/hsAqlt

`<\/al>\s*(<a\X*)<al>`

This works fine on the provided regex101 link/site, but visual studio is giving me the following error:

`Regex issue: Unrecognized escape sequence \X`

Does anyone know why this is and/or know an alternative way of achieving my goal.

Some extra info, I am using/have installed:

- Visual Studio 22, 17.0.1
- .Net 6.0
- C# 10
- System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Comment: You need `(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)`

Comment: Thanks! however This does not seem to work on regex101.com, maby I am making a mistake here or trying it wrong, Can you incorperate this in my regex as example? I am now trying this ```<\/al>\s*(<a(?>\P{M}\p{M}*))<al>``` but it wont match....

Comment: You are making a mistake trying to check a .NET regex at regex101 that is not compatible with .NET regex. And you need `</al>\s*(<a(?>\P{M}\p{M}*)*)<al>`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew , I did not now regex101 was not compatible with .net regex you saved me here!